# python.flask.Помогите найти ошибку в скрипте миграции базы данных

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Имеется скрипт :

```
import imp
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + '/versions/%03d_migration.py' % 
    (api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO) + 1)
tmp_module = imp.new_module('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, 
    SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec(str(old_model in tmp_module.__dict__))
script =api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, 
    SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO,tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print ('New migration saved as ' + migration)
print ('Current database version: ' + 
    str(api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)))
```

При запуске сервера выводится сообщение об ошибке:

> AttributeError: module 'old_model' has no attribute 'meta'

Возможно дело в том что изначально скрипт написан на python 2.7, подскажите в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: А почему tmp_module должен иметь атрибут meta? Используя `sys.new_module` вы получите пустой модуль.  Да и не понятно зачем нужна эта строка `exec(str(old_model in tmp_module.__dict__))`.

Comment: К сожалению,   затрудняюсь ответить на ваш вопрос. Исходная статья со скриптом лежит здесь - habrahabr.ru/post/196810/

Answer (score 1):

да, проблема что скринт нужно подправить для 3.x - `exec (old_model, tmp_module.__dict__)`